# How can I fill text area in Javascript or Sencha(ExtJs)?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a text area and a grid. I want the text area to fill when I click on the grid's row. I tried something like below but I can't run it.

```
try {
  var criteriaList = [];
  var XThis = this;
  var grid_2 = XThis.down("#grd_1");
  var params = grid_1.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0].data;

  var textArea_1 = this.down("#tb_3").down("#textarea_1");
  X.search.clearCriteriaList("grd_1");

  textFill = function (params) {
    try {
      if (params) {
        textArea_1.getStore().loadData(params);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      //throw exception
    }
  };
} catch (e) {
  //throw exception
}
```

How can fix it or how can I write what I want ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Text Area component, we can use `setValue` method

```
listeners: {
    itemclick: function(grid, record){
        textFieldReference.setvalue(record.get('property'))
    }
}
```

In the shared code use the 'setValue' method, instead of `textArea_1.getStore().loadData(params);` Text area don't have any store config

```
textFill = function (params) {
      try {
        if (params) {
        // if params is not object else use .prop in case if it is object
          textArea_1.setValue(params);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        //throw exception
      }
    };
```